# java facebook api chat system access

Tags: java, facebook

Does java facebook api has access to the chat system ? I can't see the package .If it does can you show it, and if it doesn't how can i access the chat system with java ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it. You may need to build your own client against the chat documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

If you're using Java, I suggest you use Smack to help with this:

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook chat is XMPP compliant so all you need to start is an XMPP lib for Java 
first gooogle result return http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview.html